# NSPredicate - Return inexact matches

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

In my app I allow users to search for vehicles by make/model using a textfield keyword search. Here is my predicate:

```
if (self.keywordSearch.text.length > 0) {

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fields.make CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR fields.model CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.keywordSearch.text, self.keywordSearch.text];            
     self.vehicleArray = [[self.vehicleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
}
```

The problem is that if the Vehicle make/model is 'Ford F-150' and the user searches F150, or F 150, the vehicle isn't included in the results. It only returns if they search F-150 or f-150.

Is there a way to make sure these inexact matches are returning?

Comment: of course there is - but you have to get clear on how inexact the result should be - if the search is `F150` would something like `... Fast 1 Big 5 Lalala 0 ...` match as well? What is your *rule*  to specify how inexact the match can be?

Comment: @luk2302 ok let's say I just wanted to allow the above case. so, hyphenated (f-150) words...user could either not include the hyphen (f150) or place a space instead of the hyphen (f 150) ... how would that predicate look?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular expressions for this. You can either use a regular expression literal inside the NSPredicate format (described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html ) or you can iterate the array manually and use an NSRegularExpression for comparing the strings.